# Bootstrap "required" class not working for current MVC web app

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working with an MVC web app. I went in to restyle the Create template and after doing so, I lost the ability to mark required fields with a red asterisk. I don't understand why my code is no longer working. Please help. Code below:

HTML/Razor Syntax

```
<div class="form-group required col-md-4">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Buy1FirstName)
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Buy1FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Buy1FirstName, "Please enter a valid first name", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

My CSS/StyleSheet

```
.form-group .required .control-label:after {
         content:" *" !important;
         color:red !important;
}
```

This is what it currently looks like. It should have a red * after the label "First Name".

[image]

Comment: Seems like an incorrect CSS selector.  Your `class=` is setting 3 classes, but your selector is looking for descendants.  Take the spaces out of your css selector and it probably will work, since `.class1.class2` chains them

Comment: Like stephen.vakil said. Your selector is incorrect. Remove the space. Should be .form-group.required .control-label:after

Comment: Tried that, and nothing is changing. I even tried taking out the col-md-4 from the <div> and that didn't change it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there are two small errors here.

1. The control-label class reference is in your css, but not in the actual html tag.
2. The css selectors are a little off just as the comments mention. I just tried your code and was able to see the red asterisk with
   these changes:

   ```
   <div class="form-group required col-md-4">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Buy1FirstName, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Buy1FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Buy1FirstName, "Please enter a valid first name", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   ```

   ```
   .form-group.required .control-label:after {
       content: " *" !important;
       color: red !important;
   }
   ```

Notice the only thing I changed was adding the class reference in the html label to "control-label", and removing the space between .form-group and .required in the css section.

Comment: Wow, I must have deleted that @class in the LabelFor when I was redesigning the layout. This fixed it perfectly. Thanks!